# ListMap: remove the m smallest element with the smallest values

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dictionary

I have to do a function that take in input a integer m, and remove the m element of the map with the smallest values.
My main problem is do this with a O(nlogn) complexity. (n is the size of the map)

This is my solution:

```
if (Map.isEmpty())
    return;
if (Map.size()<m){ //remove all keys
      Iterator<K> it=Map.keys().iterator(); //collection of all keys 
      while (it.hasNext())
          Map.remove(it.next());
}
else{
for (int i=0; i<m; i++){
   key=Map.findKeyMin() //complexity:O(n)
   Map.remove(K);
}
```

Comment: Nope, I done this, I want to emprove my implementation, in particular the complessity and to know if there is a way to do this in O(nlogn).

Comment: @Ewybe please include relevant information about what you have tried. I can offer a better solution, but need evidence you put some effort

Comment: I added my solution, but I think it's not optimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in O(n) time. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm . Essentially, you find the mth element and remove everything less than or equal to mth element.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution has complexity O(n*m) which is suboptimal. In `c++` there is a function in the `<algorithm>` header called `nth_element` this function is linear and will separate the smallest `n` elements in the collection from the others. The function is implemented using modification of the qsort algorithm and I believe this is what you need here.

Comment: If I did a quicksort on my Map and then I removed the first m elements?

Comment: The complexity of quicksort is O(n*log(n)), while what I suggest is O(n).